# 「しりとり漫才」のような、それでいてシンプルなアプリを作りたい

Tags: swift, swift2

現在Swift2を使って、市販のアプリ開発の参考書を１冊半終わらせた
プログラミング初心者です。
現在は私的な練習目的で既存のアプリを真似てみたりしています。

そこで質問なのですが、投稿型で、最初にFacebookもしくはTwitterでログインしてアプリ内でそのアカウントを使って投稿する（情報を交換し合う）ようなものを作ろうと思った場合、どのような手順でやればいいか簡単なヒントを頂けないでしょうか？

既存のアプリでは「しりとり漫才」のような、それでいてシンプルなアプリを作ろうと思っています。
Socialフレームワークを使ってゲーム内の結果をSNSに投稿することはできたのですが
その逆をやってみたいです。

Comment: facebookやtwitterなどのユーザー情報を了解するためには、まずOAuth2.0認証をする必要があります。認証に成功すれば、tokenが払い出されると思うので、それをfacebookやtwitterのAPIを叩くときに使うことで投稿などができると思いますよ。

Answer (score 1):

Parseを使用してログイン機能を実装するのもいいかもしれません

↓参考

個人のスマホアプリ開発者がParseを使うべき15の理由
http://qiita.com/koyopro/items/b9891aa7bb596b958d7e